# How to solve java printf error (java version 17 intellij idea)

Tags: java, format, printf

```
public class Time {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // ı do it randomly date
        int hour = (int) (Math.random() * 24);
        int minute = (int) (Math.random() * 60);
        int second = (int) (Math.random() * 100);

        // calculate second
        int calculate = 60 * (hour * 60) + (minute * 60) + second;

        if (hour < 12) {
            System.out.println(hour + ":" + minute + ":" + second + "am");
            System.out.println(calculate);
        } else {
            System.out.println(hour + ":" + minute + ":" + second + "pm");
            System.out.println(calculate);
        }

        int cal = ((calculate * 86400) / 100);

        // error here
        System.out.printf("Day pass: %" + cal);
    }
}
```

output

```
14:54:92pm
53732
Exception in thread "main" java.util.UnknownFormatConversionException: Conversion = '3'
    at java.base/java.util.Formatter.parse(Formatter.java:2750)
    at java.base/java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2671)
    at java.base/java.io.PrintStream.format(PrintStream.java:1209)
    at java.base/java.io.PrintStream.printf(PrintStream.java:1105)
    at Time.main(Time.java:23)
```

Comment: You should probably read the [documentation for `printf`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/io/PrintStream.html#printf(java.lang.String,java.lang.Object...))

Comment: System.out.printf("Day pass: %" + cal);  should be System.out.printf("Day pass: %d",cal);

Comment: You can use string concatenation like `System.out.println("Day pass: " + cal);`

Comment: Anyway while `%` is placeholder, it requires more information, specifically it needs to know for what kind of data it holds/reserves this place. If you want to have placeholder for series of digits like for `int` type you can use `%d`. Also first argument of `printf` is *format*. The next arguments of `printf` are *values* which should be used while printing format (those values will be printed instead of placeholders). Please note that method arguments are separated by comma, so you need `printf(yourFormat, value0, value1, etc)`.

Comment: @Pshemo Tahnk you so much it worked , ı do just delete the "+" , write "," and program worked

Comment: Aside from changing `+` to `,` you should also add `d` after `%` to make `%d` which is placeholder for series of *digits*.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

For integer in printf methode you should write "d" after "%"

change `System.out.printf("Day pass: %" + cal);`

to  `System.out.printf("Day pass: %d"  , cal);`

Comment: Thank you but that not working  ,     ı get the same error                                                                                   
     Day pass: Exception in thread "main" java.util.MissingFormatArgumentException: Format 
             specifier '%d'
 at java.base/java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2688)
 at java.base/java.io.PrintStream.format(PrintStream.java:1209)
 at java.base/java.io.PrintStream.printf(PrintStream.java:1105)
 at Time.main(Time.java:28)

Comment: Sorry I mad mistake.in printf we should use another argument it put them in % places. Check my code again.